# How did "Weird Al" Yankovic predict "The Phantom Menace"?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace, music, weird-al-yankovic

In the "Weird Al" Yankovic song *The Saga Begins*, he makes a bunch of predictions about Episode One that all seem to be valid, and unless I'm mistaken wrote the majority of the song before the film was released, and *[only made minor changes](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Saga_Begins_(song))* after seeing an advanced screening.

- Naboo was under an attack
- this here Anakin guy May be Vader someday later
- he built C-3PO
- his midi-chlorians were off the scale
- he might fulfill that prophecy
- Little Hotshot flew his plane and saved the day

[image: Screen cap from the music video]

Did he have a sneak peek at the film before he started writing? Were the trailers that revealing? Or did Jedi Al just use the Force?

Comment: Best song parody ever!  And now that I know he did it before the movie was released, even better!

Comment: Yes, this just goes to show how awesome Al is.  Two of the reasons this song was such a hit were timing and accuracy.  Both of those came from hard work.

Comment: After watching it at [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEcjgJSqSRU) I have to say I prefer it to the original ..movie ***or*** song.  ;)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

According to Weird Al's [interview on TheForce.Net](http://www.theforce.net/jedicouncil/interview/weirdal.asp), he managed to gather most of the advance intelligence from the Internet:

> The song was entirely based on Internet "rumors." I gathered all the
>   leaked info I could about the movie from all the various Star Wars
>   websites (TheForce.net was particularly helpful), and was able to
>   piece together the basic plot of the movie. We had planned to release
>   my "Running With Scissors" album the month after "Phantom Menace" came
>   out. But because of the lead time involved in recording, mixing,
>   pressing, and physically getting an album out in the stores, I had to
>   write "The Saga Begins" about two months before the movie came out.
>   The folks at Lucasfilm have always been very friendly towards me, but
>   they politely declined my requests for an advance screening or a peek
>   at the script. Thankfully, the storyline according to the Internet
>   followed the filmed storyline pretty accurately. Just for safety's
>   sake, we didn't do the final mix on "The Saga Begins" until after I
>   had seen the movie (I paid to go to the $500-a-ticket charity
>   screening, so I could see the film a couple days before the rest of
>   the world). I remember I changed a couple lines after seeing the movie
>   - very minor tweaks. Like "He's probably gonna marry her someday" was originally "I HEAR he's gonna marry her someday," because according to
>   an Internet rumor, in one scene Anakin tells the Queen to her face
>   that he's going to marry her (which, as it turns out, wasn't in the
>   final cut - but everybody knows how the storyline is going to go
>   anyway, right?)

Comment: If you want to see what TheForce.Net looked like to Weird Al, look here: http://web.archive.org/web/19990225160520/http://theforce.net/prequels/index.html Sadly, it looks like some of the links are broken or were not archived for certain dates. I remember there was a Virtual Edition website that was a mix of plot leaks and fan-made pics. The latest incarnation of this website looks to be here: http://www.theforce.net/virtualedition/index.html But it lacks the unpolished charm of the late 90's internet.

Comment: My God, has it been *that* long? I feel old...

Comment: He reconfirmed this in a recent [interview](http://www.starwars.com/news/5-great-star-wars-novelty-songs-plus-a-qa-with-the-master-weird-al-yankovic?cmp=smc|472590181&linkId=24648301) with StarWars.com.